# Conda enviroment variables location

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, environment-variables, conda

I have some environment variables that have been deleted from the registry, but seem to appear in the conda prompt. I can't seem to find where these are saved.

I can run Python and delete them for that session using

```
del os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
```

But if I start a new session then this reappears, but this has been deleted from the registry however.

Any ideas where I can find the location of these variables? It seems to be a conda issue, although I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables can be stored as configuration settings via the `conda env config vars` command. If they were originally defined in the YAML file used to create an environment, this is where they should show up. Here is the documentation on the command:

```bash
$ conda env config vars -h
usage: conda-env config vars [-h] {list,set,unset} ...

Interact with environment variables associated with Conda environments

Options:

positional arguments:
  {list,set,unset}
    list            List environment variables for a conda environment
    set             Set environment variables for a conda environment
    unset           Unset environment variables for a conda environment

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        Show this help message and exit.

examples:
    conda env config vars list -n my_env
    conda env config vars set MY_VAR=something OTHER_THING=ohhhhya
    conda env config vars unset MY_VAR
```

Packages can also manipulate environment variables via activation scripts found in `${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d`. I would strongly advise against editing anything in here. Unless you have manually added a file here, this is unlikely the source. Note that any changes made in `activate.d` scripts usually have symmetric operations in corresponding `deactivate.d` scripts.